# How do I reuse StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer with Azure ASPX Pages?

Tags: asp.net, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have an azure web app written in VBS utilizing .aspx pages. I need these pages to access my Azure-hosted Redis cache using StackExchange.Redis.

How do I share and reuse the ConnectMultiplexer object across multiple aspx pages?

When I create it on each page it works, however, every page request uses up another Redis connection and I soon run out of connections on my Redis instance and then IIS stops serving pages.

Answer (score 1):

Simply store it somewhere. Anywhere. A static variable would do, worst case. Application state (not request state) would be another option.